# SLY python can't parse simple tokens

Tags: python, parsing, token, ply, sly

I'm working on making a simple interpreted programming language using SLY to generate a AST which I will interpret without using SLY.

Currently I have been able to generate all my tokens and giving them to the parser, but it can't recognize any rule, only empty ones.

Lexer:

```
from .sly.lex import Lexer

class ALexer(Lexer):
    tokens = { ID, NUMBER, STRING, BOOL, PLUS, TIMES, MINUS, DIVIDE, ASSIGN, LPAREN, RPAREN, COMMA, NL }
    ignore = ' \t'

# Tokens
@_(r'\d+[[.]?\d*[f]?]?')
def NUMBER(self, t):
    endswithF = t.value.endswith('f')
    isfloat = endswithF or t.value.find('.') != -1
    t.value = float(t.value[:-1] if endswithF else t.value) if isfloat else int(t.value)   # Convert to a numeric value
    return t

ID = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*'
ID['true'] = BOOL
ID['false'] = BOOL

@_(r'".*"')
def STRING(self, t):
    t.value = t.value[1:-1]
    return t

# Special symbols
PLUS = r'\+'
MINUS = r'-'
TIMES = r'\*'
DIVIDE = r'/'
ASSIGN = r'='
LPAREN = r'\('
RPAREN = r'\)'
COMMA = r','

@_(r'true', r'false')
def BOOL(self, t):
    t.value = t.value == 'true'
    return t

@_(r'\n')
def NL(self, t):
    self.lineno += 1

def error(self, t):
    print("Illegal character '%s'" % t.value[0])
    self.index += 1
```

Util classes:

```
from enum import Enum

class SupportedOp(str, Enum):
    CONSTANT = "CONSTANT",
    VARIABLE = "VARIABLE",
    ARGS_LIST = "ARGS_LIST",
    FUNC_CALL = "FUNC_CALL",
    STATEMENT = "STATEMENT",
    STATEMENT_LIST = "STATEMENT_LIST",
    PROGRAM = "PROGRAM",
    SUM = '+',
    SUB = '-',
    DIV = '/',
    MUL = '*',
    ASSIGNMENT = '='

class ParsedOp(dict):
    def __init__(self, op: SupportedOp, *values):
        dict.__init__(self, op=op, values=values)
```

Parser:

```
class AParser(Parser):
debugfile = 'parser.out'
tokens = ALexer.tokens

precedence = (
      #('nonassoc', LESSTHAN, GREATERTHAN),  # Nonassociative operators
      ('left', PLUS, MINUS),
      ('left', TIMES, DIVIDE)
      #('right', UMINUS),            # Unary minus operator
 )

@_('statement_list')
def program(self, p):
    print('program', p[0])
    return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.PROGRAM, p[0])

@_('statement BACK_IN_LINES statement_list')
def statement_list(self, p):
    print('statement_list', p[0], p[1], p[2])
    lst: list = p[1].values[0]
    lst.append(p[0])
    return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.STATEMENT_LIST, lst)

@_('statement')
def statement_list(self, p):
    print('statement_list', p[0])
    return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.STATEMENT_LIST, [p[0]])

@_('empty')
def statement_list(self, p):
    print('empty statement_list')
    return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.STATEMENT_LIST, [])

@_('NL BACK_IN_LINES', 'NL')
def BACK_IN_LINES(self, p):
    print('BACK_IN_LINES', p[0])
    #unused
    return 'NL'

@_('assignment', 'expr')
def statement(self, p):
    print('statement', p[0])
    return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.STATEMENT, p[0])

@_('ID ASSIGN expr')
def assignment(self, p):
    print('assignment', p[0], p[1], p[2])
    return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.ASSIGNMENT, p[0], p[2])

@_('expr COMMA expr_list')
def expr_list(self, p):
    print('expr_list', p[0], p[1], p[2])
    lst: list = p[1].values[0]
    lst.append(p[0])
    return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.ARGS_LIST, lst)

@_('expr')
def expr_list(self, p):
    print('expr_list', p[0])
    return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.ARGS_LIST, [p[0]])

@_('empty')
def expr_list(self, p):
    print('empty expr_list')
    return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.ARGS_LIST, [])

@_('constant')
def expr(self, p):
    print('expr', p[0])
    return p[0]

@_('ID')
def expr(self, p):
    print('expr', p[0])
    return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.VARIABLE, p[0])

@_('LPAREN expr RPAREN')
def expr(self, p):
    print('expr', p[0], p[1], p[2])
    return p[1]

@_('ID LPAREN expr_list RPAREN')
def expr(self, p):
    print('expr', p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3])
    #if exists p.ID in functions
    return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.FUNC_CALL, p.ID, p.expr_list)

@_( 'expr PLUS expr',
    'expr MINUS expr',
    'expr TIMES expr',
    'expr DIVIDE expr')
def expr(self, p):
    print('expr', p[0], p[1], p[2])
    return ParsedOp(SupportedOp(p[1]), p[0], p[2])

@_('NUMBER', 'STRING', 'BOOL')
def constant(self, p):
    print('constant', p[0])
    return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.CONSTANT, p[0])

@_('')
def empty(self, p):
    print('empty')
    pass

def error(self, p):
    if p:
        print("Syntax error at token", p.type)
        # Just discard the token and tell the parser it's okay.
        self.errok()
    else:
        print("Syntax error at EOF")
```

I don't know if all my rules are ok but I commented every rule leaving uncommented only the "constant" rule which is straightforward, still can't recognize it.

Main:

```
tokens_out = lexer.ALexer().tokenize(event.get("code"))
tree = AParser().parse(tokens_out)
```

All my tokens are well recognized so the Lexer is ok. The parser can't recognize any rule. Any idea?

Comment: I can't run your program because you don't include your lexer and I don't know the details of the problem because you don't show me what evidence you have for the assertion that no rule is recognized. If you don't provide a [mre], you force us to play 20 Questions in comment threads, which is neither efficient nor gratifying. (Also, take a look at [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291240/1566221).)

Comment: Anyway, disabling rules won't allow the parser to recognise more. It can only make it recognise less. If Sly is reporting parser conflicts, you should resolve them before trying anything else. And you should definitely mention them in your question.

Comment: @rici I added the lexer in my post, about the problem it's just that it doesn't recognize any rules except the empty one, if I delete the empty one I get EOF error in my parser.
I also tried to leave only the constant rule and be the start of the parser but still get EOF

Comment: 20 Questions continued: What exactly does `event.get("code")` return?

Comment: @rici event.get("code") is a string of the code I am supposed to parse, I'm passing it to the Lexer to get tokens from it, anything is fine as input like "x = 2" or any statement described inside the parser method.
The problem is the one I texted in my prev messages, I dont have any conflicts, It just dont recognize my tokens

Comment: So, as it turns out, the problem wasn't that your tokens weren't being recognised (except for the newline token, which was recognised by the tokeniser but then discarded instead of being passed to the parser). The rest of the problems are detailed in the answer. I want to emphasize here that while it looked to you like tokens were not begin recognised, that was actually an artefact of the way you produce debugging information. This sort of issue is precisely why we always request an [mre]  as well as a detailed problem description including the literal inputs which produce the problem.

Comment: I know it seems like a lot of work (and more so if you actually create a simplified version of the program in order to actually minimize the supposedly minimal example). But that's what it takes to debug a program. Debugging can be arduous. And that's doubly the case when you're trying to debug someone else's code. Anyway, good luck with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, your code works fine up to the point at which you attempt to parse the second statement. I tried it with the input `x=2` as suggested in your comment, and it produced the following result (pretty-printed with the `pprint` module):

```
{ 'op': <SupportedOp.PROGRAM: 'PROGRAM'>,
  'values': ( { 'op': <SupportedOp.STATEMENT_LIST: 'STATEMENT_LIST'>,
                'values': ( [ { 'op': <SupportedOp.STATEMENT: 'STATEMENT'>,
                                'values': ( { 'op': <SupportedOp.ASSIGNMENT: '='>,
                                              'values': ( 'x',
                                                          { 'op': <SupportedOp.CONSTANT: 'CONSTANT'>,
                                                            'values': ( 2,)})},)}],)},)}
```

But once you try to parse two statements --say `x=2` and `y=2` on separate lines-- things start to fall apart.

There are several issues, which I'll try to deal with one at a time.

The first problem is that your `NL` lexer rule does not return anything, which means that no token is emitted. That means that the `BACK_IN_LINES` rule cannot match, because it is expecting to see one or more `NL` tokens. This generates a cascade of parser errors, which you should have seen on your console.

It's easy to get confused about the parser's progress. Since the parser doesn't see the `NL` token, what it sees is `x = 2 y ...`. At the moment at which it sees the `y`, it hasn't yet reduced `expr`; after all, the next token might have been a `+` or other operator. But an `ID` is not one of the possible tokens which can follow `2`, so a syntax error is thrown immediately, with the result that `expr`, `statement` and `statement_list` are not reduced, and so their reduction actions never execute, and thus you never see any of the debugging output you've put in the reduction actions. That doesn't really mean that the rule was not recognised; it would be more accurate to say that the rule was recognised but a longer match was still possible.

If you fix the lexer by adding `return t` at the end of the `NL` rule, then you run into the second problem, which is the reduction action for `statement_list: statement BACK_IN_LINES statement_list`. This bug causes the parse to fail even for an input consisting only of `x=2`, if that input is terminated with a newline character. The action is triggered because `BACK_IN_LINES` is now recognised, so the grammar requires that the `statement_list has two subcomponents, a` statement `(`x=2`) and a`  statement_list`consisting of the rest of the input. The rest of the input is empty, which is OK because you allow a`statement_list` to match an empty input. But, as I said, that causes the reduction action to execute, and that reduction action includes:

```py
lst: list = p[1].values[0]
```

That line has several problems. First, `p[1]` is the `BACK_IN_LINES` grammar symbol; you obviously intended to use `p[2]`, which is the `statement_list`. So `p[1]` is the string `NL`, which doesn't have a `values` attribute. (That should be evident from the Python traceback, assuming that you can see the exception tracebacks. If you can't, you should seriously consider debugging in a Python console instead of whatever you are using.)

But when we fix it to use `p[2]` instead, we still get a Python TypeError exception. Instead of complaining that a `str` has no `values` attribute, it now complains that a `builtin_function_or_method` is not subscriptable. The `builtin_function_or_method` is the `values` method of a `dict` object, becasue `p[2]` is a `SupportedOp`, which is subclassed from `dict`. If you had intended to use the `values` method, you would have had to have called it, but I don't think that was what you intended (and therefore the `values` key is perhaps badly named). What you actually meant was the value associated with the `values` key, which means that the line should read:

```py
lst: list = p[2]["values"][0]
```

But that's still a bit problematic. Let's take a look at the parsed result of the input consisting of three lines:

```
first = 1
second = 2
third = 3
```

That produces (again, pretty printed with `pprint`):

```
{ 'op': <SupportedOp.PROGRAM: 'PROGRAM'>,
  'values': ( { 'op': <SupportedOp.STATEMENT_LIST: 'STATEMENT_LIST'>,
                'values': ( [ { 'op': <SupportedOp.STATEMENT: 'STATEMENT'>,
                                'values': ( { 'op': <SupportedOp.ASSIGNMENT: '='>,
                                              'values': ( 'third',
                                                          { 'op': <SupportedOp.CONSTANT: 'CONSTANT'>,
                                                            'values': ( 3,)})},)},
                              { 'op': <SupportedOp.STATEMENT: 'STATEMENT'>,
                                'values': ( { 'op': <SupportedOp.ASSIGNMENT: '='>,
                                              'values': ( 'second',
                                                          { 'op': <SupportedOp.CONSTANT: 'CONSTANT'>,
                                                            'values': ( 2,)})},)},
                              { 'op': <SupportedOp.STATEMENT: 'STATEMENT'>,
                                'values': ( { 'op': <SupportedOp.ASSIGNMENT: '='>,
                                              'values': ( 'first',
                                                          { 'op': <SupportedOp.CONSTANT: 'CONSTANT'>,
                                                            'values': ( 1,)})},)}],)},)}
```

If you look carefully at that output, you'll see that the three statements are indeed there, *but in the wrong order*.

That's the result of your choosing to use a right-recursive rule for `statement_list`:

```
statement_list: statement BACK_IN_LINES statement_list
```

Right-recursive rules are practically never correct for bottom-up parsers (such as the LALR(1) parser generated by Sly), although there are times when they are needed. If you can choose between a left-recursive rule and a right-recursive rule, your best option is the left-recursive rule:

```
statement_list: statement_list BACK_IN_LINES statement
```

This has two advantages. First, it doesn't require use of the parser stack to hold all the intermediate and incomplete subparses of `statement_list` until the end of the list is reached. More importantly, it executes the reduction actions for the recursive non-terminal in the order you probably expect them to be executed, which is left-to-right.

The right-recursive rule executes the reduction actions right-to-left, because the first recursive reduction is the last nested `statement_list`. And the consequence is that which we have already seen: the `statement`s are appended to the `statement_list` in reverse order, starting with the last one.

It's easy to rewrite the rule as left-recursive. But if we do a naive change, we'll end up with a different problem. It's (probably) desirable that the input is allowed to but not required to end with a newline. That worked with the right-recursive production because `statement_list` was allowed to be empty. But that won't help with the left-recursive rule; a left-recursive rule with an `empty` option puts the `empty` option at the beginning of the list (precisely because it produces the list left-to-right). With the left-recursive rule, it's more convenient to allow `statement` to be empty. But instead of adding an "empty statement", which will clutter up the AST, we can just add a rule to `statement_list` which accepts an empty sequence instead of a statement. Once we do that, we eliminate the need for `BACK_IN_LINES`, because the grammatical logic is kept in `statement_list`.

So we can remove `BACK_IN_LINES` and replace the rules for `statement_list` with the following:

```py
    @_('statement')
    def statement_list(self, p):
        print('statement_list', p[0])
        return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.STATEMENT_LIST, [p[0]])
    
    @_('empty')
    def statement_list(self, p):
        print('empty statement_list')
        return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.STATEMENT_LIST, [])
    
    @_('statement_list NL')
    def statement_list(self, p):
        print('statement_list', p[0])
        return p[0]
    
    @_('statement_list NL statement')
    def statement_list(self, p):
        print('statement_list', p[0], p[1], p[2])
        lst: list = p[0]["values"][0]
        lst.append(p[2])
        return ParsedOp(SupportedOp.STATEMENT_LIST, lst)
```

Now, finally, we get the expected parse:

```
{ 'op': <SupportedOp.PROGRAM: 'PROGRAM'>,
  'values': ( { 'op': <SupportedOp.STATEMENT_LIST: 'STATEMENT_LIST'>,
                'values': ( [ { 'op': <SupportedOp.STATEMENT: 'STATEMENT'>,
                                'values': ( { 'op': <SupportedOp.ASSIGNMENT: '='>,
                                              'values': ( 'first',
                                                          { 'op': <SupportedOp.CONSTANT: 'CONSTANT'>,
                                                            'values': ( 1,)})},)},
                              { 'op': <SupportedOp.STATEMENT: 'STATEMENT'>,
                                'values': ( { 'op': <SupportedOp.ASSIGNMENT: '='>,
                                              'values': ( 'second',
                                                          { 'op': <SupportedOp.CONSTANT: 'CONSTANT'>,
                                                            'values': ( 2,)})},)},
                              { 'op': <SupportedOp.STATEMENT: 'STATEMENT'>,
                                'values': ( { 'op': <SupportedOp.ASSIGNMENT: '='>,
                                              'values': ( 'third',
                                                          { 'op': <SupportedOp.CONSTANT: 'CONSTANT'>,
                                                            'values': ( 3,)})},)}],)},)}
```